# nxos private vlan problem

Tags: cisco-nx-os

my carrier assigned a 10Gbps/SFP+ port to me and it's connected to my Nexus 5672UP and here is my config port and VLANs config :

```
interface Ethernet1/4
  description MYCARRIER
  no cdp enable
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1001,2622

  
  
  
  interface Vlan1001
  description X
  no shutdown
  ip access-group X in
  ipv6 traffic-filter X in
  no ip redirects
  ip address 185.Y.Y.Y/29
  ipv6 address YYYY/64
  ipv6 nd retrans-timer 1000
  ipv6 nd suppress-ra
  no ipv6 redirects

  
  
  
  interface Vlan2622
  description UPLINK
  no shutdown
  ip address 185.200.x.x/30
```

each vlan is connected to a different provider. VLAN 1001 is connected to Provider A and VLAN 2622 is connected to Provider B and my connection provider configures the 10G port in their side as a private VLAN. i can connect to Provider A without any problem but I can not connect to Provider B or ping it and when I checked the mac address I understand my provider B mac address learned by VLAN 1001 and 2622 but mac address for provider A just learn from VLAN 1001,
CAn somebody help me?
here is my mac address output:

```
show mac address-table | i 3c8c.9389.xxxx
* 1001     3c8c.9389.xxxx    dynamic   0          F    F  Eth1/4
* 2622     3c8c.9389.xxxx    dynamic   40         F    F  Eth1/4
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the VLAN 2622 SVI can't ARP the next hop's IP address, L2 connectivity is broken - either on your side or further up. The MAC addresses are only an indication if you know what they should be. You have created the VLANs, haven't you?

Comment: yes i already create the VLAN and i have next-hop arp in my switch, so it seems there is layer3 problem , right?

Comment: Can you ping the next hop (assuming that it does support ICMP echo)?

Comment: no i can not ping it, i have next-hop arp in my switch but the other side told me they do not have my mac in their own switches

Comment: That's an L2 problem - how does ARP work when L2 doesn't?

Comment: but I am curious, if it's an L2 problem why do I have their ARP and mac address in my switch but they do not have my own in their switches?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132433/discussion-between-blackmetal-and-zac67).